# What does this BRP factory manual mean by "fiber hammer"?

Tags: tools, tool-identification

I'm gearing up to do some maintenance on a BRP watercraft and I came across this statement in the factory manual:

> "3. Using a *fiber hammer*, gently tap impeller cover to help release it from the jet pump housing"

Here it is in context:

[image]

Of all the different manuals and catalogs I've read and jobs I've worked I've never heard the term "fiber hammer".  I suppose "fiber hammer" could mean "block of wood used like a hammer", but that's just a guess.  I suppose they mean some sort of non-marring hammer, but I'm not sure.  [Googling "fiber hammer"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=fiber+hammer&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=838&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq26_Vg4jPAhUU2GMKHdF3DiwQsAQIIg) just turns up hammers with fiberglass handles.  [McMaster-Carr](http://mcmaster.com) doesn't list any "fiber hammers" in their index.

What, exactly, is a fiber hammer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure, but would assume they are stating something like a dead blow hammer or possibly a hammer with a non-metal face. Something which might look like this:

[image]

You're looking for a hammer which is nonmetallic in nature so as to not damage the surface of what you're working on.